# Write space with TCPDF into a PDF file

Tags: php, pdf, whitespace, tcpdf

I've this simple script that write some text into a PDF trought the php library TCPDF.
This is the script:

```
// create new PDF document 
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Label Creator');
$pdf->SetTitle('labels');
$pdf->SetSubject('Labels di prova');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

//set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE,0);

//set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

//set some language-dependent strings
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('times', '', 15);
//left margin
$pdf->SetMargins(18,15,18,FALSE);
// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();
$label="Hello world, i'm michele";

$pdf->Cell(0, 0 , $label, 0, 1, 'C', 0, '', 0,FALSE,'T','M');

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('../../labels.pdf', 'F');
echo 'Labels generate!';
```

the problem is that the script works, but in the file I'll see the text without spaces! Like this:
helloworld,i'mmichele
Does anyone have the solution?!!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I've resolved, the problem is a bug with the browser's PDF plug-in visualizer!!**

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: If you want to use Cell**

The prototype is:

```
//Cell($w, $h=0, $txt='', $border=0, $ln=0, $align='', $fill=0, $link='', $stretch=0, $ignore_min_height=false, $calign='T', $valign='M')
```

*To deal with spacing, use these:*

```
$pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'TEST CELL STRETCH: spacing', 1, 1, 'C', 0, '', 3);
$pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'TEST CELL STRETCH: force spacing', 1, 1, 'C', 0, '', 4);
```

*You can try this:*

```
$label="Hello world, i'm michele";
$pdf->Cell(0, 0 , $label, 1, 1, 'C', 0, '', 3;
```

The border is on, so that you can see if the cell is large enough. Hope this works.
(for indication, what follows : FALSE,'T','M' are already the values by default)

**Option 2: You can also use Write()**

```
$pdf->AddPage();

// set some text to print
$label = <<<EOD
About Michele.

Michele is awesome.
EOD;

// print a block of text using Write()
$pdf->Write($h=0, $label, $link='', $fill=0, $align='C', $ln=true, $stretch=0, $firstline=false, $firstblock=false, $maxh=0);
```

You can find plenty of examples there: [TCPDF examples](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php)

Comment: Sorry but $label="Hello world, i'm michele";
$pdf->Cell(0, 0 , $label, 1, 1, 'C', 0, '', 3; doesn't write spaces...

Comment: I've resolved, the problem is a bug with the browser's PDF plug-in visualizer!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem lies with the "times" font. I had the same problems with that particular font. You can try some of the other fonts in the tcpdf fonts directory.

Comment: I've resolved, the problem is a bug with the browser's PDF plug-in visualizer!!